# Docker: How to health check a container that dont have port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

In my AWS ECS Task, I have 5 containers. One of them is `queue` container and it failes sometime if queue load is too much or something. I want to use help of `healthcheck` to check container health and restart it after some times.

This aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-healthcheck.html) explains it. but my container dont have nginx or port 80 and it gives `refuse connection` error.

```
[ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1" ]
```

How can I do this check when I dont have port 80 or nginx inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

The health check should be specific for your application. How would you know its still running? `ps aux` command perhaps to validate that a process for your script is running?

Switch the curl part for that

Answer (score 0):

A possible way could be developing an alarm on a [Custom Metric in CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html).

Your container would publish some metric specific to your container functionality, e.g. **your queue length**.

Then you define and **alarm on that metric**. When the alarm is in breaching state, you can **execute an action** (through SNS and Lambda) to terminate the task, or do what you require.

Answer (score 0):

One option to healthcheck a container that isn't running anything on port 80 is to check to see if a file exists... and then run a check every so often and decide to delete / keep that file if your check fails / passes.

Check out this contrived example below:

[image]

When running docker ps now, you will see "healthy" in the status of the container. Alternatively if you place the counter at "-1", and rerun docker-compose-up --build, the container will become "unhealthy".

Additionally, If a container has a healthcheck in the dockerfile, the container will know whether or not it's healthy. From there, you can inspect the container's health by running this command `docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health}}' CONTAINER_ID`

This doesn't answer the question on how to do a health check from AWS ECS, but it does answer how to do a healthcheck without something running on port 80. I hope this helps someone out!